# Can't install PostSharp 4.3 to Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, postsharp

[image: http://i.imgur.com/64LruRp.png]

I can't find the option to add my postsharp to visual studo 2017 and was wondering if there was a way to fix that? I've tried a ton of stuff including reinstalling, looking for it in any options menu and nuget pakcages and can't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [Version 5](https://www.postsharp.net/downloads/postsharp-5.0) if you want to use Postsharp within Visual Studio 2017.

The version 4.3 only supports up to VS2015.

Comment: This is incorrect AFAIK. Run the installer, navigate to the temp folder that the installer creates, and a 2017 VSIX is in there